# Отправка файла с помощью telegramAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Пишу бота для телеграмма. Бот генерирует файл file.csv рядом с main.py.
Этот файл необходимо отправить с сервера в чат.

```
def send_document(self, chat_id, document): 
    params = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'document': document}
    method = 'sendDocument'
    headers = {'content-type': "multipart/form-data"}
    resp = requests.post(self.api_url + method, headers, params)
    return resp
bot.send_document(last_chat_id, open('file.csv', 'rb'))
```

Пробовал так, возвращается ошибка
`{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: there is no document in the request"}`

Подскажите в чем ошибка?

Comment: Ну вам же пишет, в запросе нет документа. Что-же - это может значить  ^.^

Comment: Я понимаю что он мне пишет, но не понимаю почему и что сделать чтобы документ в запросе был :) в коде перед запросом пишу```print(document)```в консоли вижу ```<_io.BufferedReader name='file.csv'>``` значит документ должен вставляться в запрос, разве нет?

Comment: Тебе нужно просто отправить этот файл или то, что находится внутри файла?

Comment: сам файл отправить

Answer (score 0):

Покажу пример того как я отправлял здесь:

```
def save(message):
    file_to_send = open('client.txt', 'rb') #Открытие в двоичном режиме
    bot.send_document(chat_id=(айди чата), data=file_to_send) #Отправка файла
    file_to_send.close()
    os.remove('client.txt')
```